# why does an error in list<> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

i am new to class/object.I am  getting this error. I don't know why this is not navigating to the desired page. There is my code. Thanks for helping~~

### WebService1.asmx.cs

```
public class yearList
{
    public yearList(){}
    public int year;
    public List<int> list;

    public List<int> List()
    {
         for (int i = -2; i < 3; i++)
        {
            list.Add(year+i);
        }
         return list;
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public List<int> List()
{
    yearList yl = new yearList();
    string connStr2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["taisangrent_sql"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connStr2);

    string strSQL2 = "select YEAR(getdate()) as year";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, conn2);

    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    adapter2.Fill(ds2, "y_m");

    yl.year = int.Parse(ds2.Tables["y_m"].Rows[0]["year"].ToString());
    return yl.List();                    
}
```

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing..

```
public List<int> list;
```

to

```
public List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

When you're calling `list.Add(year);`, the list object has now yet been *newed up*, so that's why you're getting the error.

I think it would be better to change the method name too...

`public List<int> GetList()` instead of `public List<int> List();`

**EDIT**: Good point by @Hassan

just to clarify, the [DataAdapter.Fill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163799.aspx) will Open/Close connections automatically.

> One of the great features of ADO.NET is that the DataAdapter object's
>   Fill and Update methods can open and close a connection automatically.
>   The advantage of this is that it is not necessary to open the
>   connection explicitly because the DataAdapter opens it for you at the
>   moment right before it executes its SQL command against the database
>   and then closes it right afterwards.

Comment: please note `new List<int>;` should be `new List<int>();`

Comment: Also please notice that sqlconnection is not opened and closed? do you think it is required here? I think it will good to recommend `using` statement.

Comment: @HassanNisar, the `.Fill()` will implicitly call `open` & `close`, as far as I remember from ADO.NET days :)

Comment: @bbqwings, this seems to be a different question?  However, you're only adding the year **2014** to the `year` variable, so that's what you should be getting back? What were you trying to return?

Comment: OK, I'm guessing you could have done something like `list.Add(year+i);`, but that's a guess since I don't know the requirement.

Comment: i found another question, if i add `static` into webmethod, how do i use webmethod at .cs? or can i do that? THANKS

Answer (score 0):

When declaring as

```
public List<int> list;
```

your object is just creating, it wont assign the memory to it. So just decalre it like

```
public List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

And also try to give some other name to your function if its not a constructor as it already a class name.

Comment: just a correction to add brackets in end public List<int> list = new List<int>();